# curl_getinfo returning -1 as content-length

Tags: php, curl

I am building a website crawler and using a [cURL class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1988-PHP-cURL-extension-wrapper-access-remote-Web-resources.html) with these options for getting headers, so that I can extract their `mime/type` and `content-length` before downloading full site to very it as `text/html` and below specified size limits.

these are my curl options

```
$c->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, $theURL);
$c->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$c->setopt(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$c->setopt(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$c->setopt(CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
$c->setopt(CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
$c->setopt(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
$c->setopt(CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 2);

// Within Class
$theReturnValue = curl_exec($this->m_handle);
$this->m_status = curl_getinfo($this->m_handle) ;
```

but it always return `[download_content_length] => -1` even without `CURLOPT_NOBODY` however the data (whole file) retrived is correct.

Comment: Perhaps the server isn't sending a `content-length` header?

Comment: Sorry for less information (I have edited question now).. but this does seems to be the case, what should I do when I want to retrieve html pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The libcurl docs for [CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html#CURLINFOCONTENTLENGTHDOWNLOAD) (which is what the PHP binding is using) says:

> "this returns -1 if the size isn't known"

Comment: Is there a way to force get size, without downloading it first?

Comment: No.  You can't force a server to return a `Content-Length` header.  It's very common for dynamically generated pages to omit this header, as headers are often sent before the page is even completely rendered on the server side -- at the time headers are sent, not even the server knows how large the page will be.