# cURL won't get file size for a particular PDF

Tags: php, pdf, curl

I've got a script that uses cURL to check the file size of a bunch of PDFs. It works great, except for with one particular PDF.  For this one PDF, it tells me the file size is -1.  The PDF is https://www.panerabread.com/content/dam/panerabread/documents/nutrition/Panera-Nutrition.pdf

Here is my code:

```
            $ch = curl_init($pdf_url);
        $fh = fopen('/dev/null', 'w');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
        // Execute
        curl_exec($ch);

        // Check if any error occured
        if(!curl_errno($ch))
        {
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

        $size=$info['download_content_length'];
        }
        else echo'error!';

        // Close handle
        curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked before.  I found this and a bunch of other answers searching google for "download_content_length is negative one":

[curl_getinfo returning -1 as content-length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518323/curl-getinfo-returning-1-as-content-length)

Apparently if the server doesn't set the Content-Length header, then you'll get a -1.  Have you tried looking at the response headers when you download the PDF?

EDIT:  I checked and the Content-Length header isn't set in the response from the server.

You could always download the file to a temporary location and get the size using the `filesize` function

Answer (score 0):

The field will contain `-1` if something went wrong while "calculating" the field. The problem with this particular file is that the server sends the wrong `Content-Length` header. The header says `112189` bytes where the real size of the downloaded file is `144418` bytes.

I suggest to use

```
$info['size_download']
```

this is independent from what the remote server sends, it is the measured file size in bytes.